# How to swap two strings in a single line in alphabetic order?

Tags: c#

Good day all,

I want to swap two strings in a single line based on its alphabetic order.

Example:

Arun 2012, Gopi 2010, Dinesh 2012. Computer Networks, Tata McGraw Hill. 745:19-22

In this line author names Likely Arun, Dinesh, Gopi have to swap in alphabetical order and saved in a same file for reference.

How could it possible to swap exactly the string array?

Here is what I tried:

```
foreach (string strPara in strParaValue) 
{ 
   string[] strAuthorsPart = strPara.Split('.'); 
   string[] strAuthorslist = strAuthorsPart[0].Split(','); 
   string[] strAuthor = strAuthorslist[0].Split(' '); 
   if (strSplitValue[0].Contains(strAuthor[0].Trim())) 
   { 
      swt.WriteLine(strAuthor[0] + "\t"); 
   } 
   else 
   {
      swf.WriteLine(strAuthor[0] + "\t"); 
   }
}
```

Thanks
DeeGo.

Comment: How will you know how the strings are separated, and which of the strings are names? In your example, Computer Networks would come between Arun 2012 and Dinesh 2012.

Comment: Let me explain my requirements I have a word file which having Author References. In that some of the reference may changed (In case of multiple author) improperly. I want swap that author name and made changes in alphabetical order.

Comment: So your expected output string would be what? Because there are 2 delimiters in the above string and you would need to know what you need to do with them. And what have you tried yourself?

Comment: Your explanation of the requirements have nothing to do with the problem you posted... They only introduce new problems, like how will you know which paragraph in the document contains names that need to be swapped.

Comment: Yes i tried. I separate the strings into string arrays.

Comment: show more input strings and expected output strings

Comment: foreach (string strPara in strParaValue)
                {
                    string[] strAuthorsPart = strPara.Split('.');
                    string[] strAuthorslist = strAuthorsPart[0].Split(',');
                    string[] strAuthor = strAuthorslist[0].Split(' ');
                    if (strSplitValue[0].Contains(strAuthor[0].Trim()))
                    {
                        swt.WriteLine(strAuthor[0] + "\t");
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        swf.WriteLine(strAuthor[0] + "\t");
                    }

Comment: Mr Lister, I get all the author references as New string and split every single author name into string array.

Comment: You should edit your question and add that in, as well as an expected output string.

Comment: next time edit question and add formatted code.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
string tosort = " Arun 2012, Gopi 2010, Dinesh 2012. Computer Networks, Tata McGraw Hill. 745:19-22";
string sortedAuthors = "";
string sortedTexts = "";
List<string> mylist = tosort.Split(new[]{',', '.'}).ToList<string>();
mylist.Sort();
mylist.ForEach(n => if(n.Substring.IndexOf(" ").sorted += n + ",");
```

This will produce the output

> " 745:19-22, Arun 2012, Computer Networks, Dinesh 2012, Gopi 2010,
>   Tata McGraw Hill,"

**Based on your comment**, try this:

```
string tosort = " Arun 2012, Gopi 2010, Dinesh 2012. Computer Networks, Tata McGraw Hill. 745:19-22";
string sortedAuthors = "";
string sortedTexts = "";
List<string> mylist = tosort.Split(new[] { ',', '.' }).ToList<string>();
mylist.Sort(); int i;
foreach (var n in mylist)
{
    if (Int32.TryParse(n.Substring(n.IndexOf(' ')).Trim(), out i))
    {
        sortedAuthors += (n + ", ");
    }
    else
    {
        sortedTexts += (n + ", ");
    }
}
string final = sortedAuthors + ", " + sortedTexts;
```

**This will output**:

> ,  745:19-22,  Arun 2012,  Computer Networks,  Dinesh 2012,  Gopi
>   2010,  Tata McGraw Hill,

I believe you can handle the rest.

Comment: You're splitting on spaces there, I believe?

Comment: Mr Lister, Yes in the above i mentioned code i had split the Reference author by means of (.)full stop (,) comma and ( )spaces

Comment: Chibueze, I want this type of output "Arun 2012, Dinesh 2012, Gopi 2010. Computer Networks, Tata McGraw Hill. 745:19-22" Swapping need only for the Author names not more than that

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get the strings you are sorting in some container, like Array. For example string[] strings = s.Split(','). Be sure to get only the part with author names in your case. Then you can sort the result array in any convinient way, for example: Array.Sort(strings). Then create new string from them: string newline = string.Join(",",strings) and concat it with waht you had before. Remember that any operations with string modifications actually produce new string object, because strings are immutable, so no kind of "in-place" sort is possible

Comment: In my data Every string array (Author Name) is separated by (,) comma and ends with (.) full stop at the end of the author for every references

Comment: Thanks for your timely suggesion

Answer (score 0):

after you find `strAuthorslist` your task is easy:

```
string[] strAuthorsPart = strPara.Split('.'); 
string[] strAuthorslist = strAuthorsPart[0].Split(','); 
strAuthorslist.Sort();
var newAuthorsArrangement = String.Join(strAuthorslist, ",");
var updatedLine = newAuthorsArrangement  + "." +
                  strPara.SkipWhile(x=>x!='.').ToString();
```

I used .Net 4 [SkipWhile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549075.aspx) method, but you can simply handle last part with .Net 1.1